# Asp.Net Core HTTP Error 500.53 - URL Rewrite Module Error on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to determine the cause of a 500 server error I'm seeing in the diagnostics logs for my AspNetCore 2.1.5 app that's running in an Azure App Service instance:

> HTTP Error 500.53 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
>   Outbound rewrite rules cannot be applied when the content of the HTTP response is encoded ("gzip").

Symptoms include:

1. Incomplete HTML responses (A 200 status code is returned, but occasionally only a portion of the content is displayed - refreshing the page 1-3 times usually fixes this)
2. Frequently slow response times ~10-40 sec - it's as if the app isn't warmed up.

Possibly Relevant Information:

- Application insights doesn't show any of these failures or slow response times anywhere.
- I'm not explicitly using any rewrite rules in my config.
- Calling/Not Calling app.UseResponseCompression() in startup doesn't make a difference
- Calling/Not Calling app.UseHttpsRedirection() in startup doesn't make a difference
- Enabling/Disabling "Https Only" in the azure portal doesn't make a difference
- I'm not seeing any problems locally
- Scaling between B1,B2,S1,S2 app service plans doesn't make a difference
- Turning off https only and using non-ssl endpoints doesn't make a difference

Here's my WebHostBuilder call:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
})
.UseSerilog()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseApplicationInsights();
```

The only similar results I find when Googling for this are 500.52 errors, but they're always related to incorrect url rewrite rules which I'm not (explicity) using.

Answer (score 6):

For others benefit, I recently hit on the same issue, after 2 hours deep diving into Azure portal, there seems a known issue with application insight with `APPINSIGHTS_JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED` setting enabled combined with `<urlCompression ...>` settings, you can find more details from the link below

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/issues/282

### Two possible solutions

#### 1. Turn off `APPINSIGHTS_JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED`

Set `APPINSIGHTS_JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED` to `false` either from your web.config appSetting or Azure App blade applicaiton setting

#### 2. Turn off `dynamicCompressionBeforeCache`

Search in the web.config and Find `<urlCompression ..>` node, disable both static and dynamic compression
`<urlCompression doStaticCompression="false" doDynamicCompression="false" />`.

If you have CDN like cloudflare configured, you should consider to remove `urlCompression` completely.

Comment: It worked with setting APPINSIGHTS_JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED to false in my case

Comment: @vincent You have saved my life!! I just migrated our working app from ASEv2 to ASEv3 and was hitting this issue; the `APPINSIGHTS_JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED` worked for me ... thank you